# Why would Application#call be slow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rack

For some reason my `::Application#call` is incredibly slow. In one case it took `3,840ms` according to New Relic's instrumentation.

The documentation just describes this method as: `Implements call according to the Rack API. It simply dispatches the request to the underlying middleware stack.`

It takes over 5 seconds to even get to `ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet#call`, let alone my controller's method.

Why might this be so slow? And where could I try to instrument to dig into this further?

None of my middlewares look to be particularly odd, either:

```
use Raven::Rack
use #<ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware:0x007fd836083e08>
use Rack::Runtime
use ActionDispatch::RequestId
use Rails::Rack::Logger
use Rack::Cors
use ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions
use ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions
use ActionDispatch::RemoteIp
use ActionDispatch::Callbacks
use ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement
use ActiveRecord::QueryCache
use ActionDispatch::ParamsParser
use Clearance::RackSession
use Rack::Head
use Rack::ConditionalGet
use Rack::ETag
use ActionDispatch::Flash
use Rack::SslEnforcer
run CookacademyApi::Application.routes
```

Comment: Did you check the middleware instrumentation on New Relic? If there's something slow between the call to the app and the call to the routes, it might be a middleware. To see what's in your middleware stack, you can run `rake middleware`.

Comment: @fivedigit The middelware instrumentation doesn't appear to show me much: http://cl.ly/image/1B3P143p2g3K

Comment: @JoshSmith Did you find any solution? I am also facing the same issue

Comment: @JoshSmith same issue here, anything?

Comment: yea newrelic is really not that useful :(

Comment: I've seen this as well and hope to get an answer one day. However I will note that we saw far fewer of these errors when we began using Nginx. I don't want to make this comment an answer because it's so flimsy. All I can say is the setup was a rails 4 app on heroku originally configured with Unicorn and no nginx. Adding nginx made fewer of these slow calls.

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely too much on NewRelic metrics. I recently got the same issue with a page NR estimated around 3s to load. After closing a couple of applications and restarting firefox NR showed less than 300ms